# How to add new items in listview at the top in android

Tags: android, listview, sorting, android-listview

I am having a ListView in which i am showing list items fetched from shared preference, now when every time new list item includes it includes below the first one, is there any way to update listview in such a way that new item included will be at the top. In short incoming item should be at top. Below is my code base :

I tried

```
Collections.reverse(yourList);
```

before setting adapter but it works sometimes and sometimes when again i open activity it won't work

Comment: This condition really bugs me: "if (count != 0 && count >= 50 ... "

Comment: `items.add(new EntryItem(first, second));` => `items.add(new EntryItem(first, second), 0);`

Comment: @smitalm - That's another part to flush list view. But here we are talking about sorting at top when new item included

Comment: So you dont find anything wrong with that condition?

Comment: fyi keeping static reference to a context is a big nono

Comment: @smitalm - I am sorry, i am not able to catch the mistake, can u help me in recalling..Thanks

Comment: if your count is >= 50, then it is by definition !0, i.e. the `count != 0` is logically unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try by replacing the

```
items.add(new EntryItem(first, second));
```

in addItems() by

```
items.add(0, new EntryItem(first, second));
```

Comment: if you have a list of items you can do addAll(0, yourArrayList); Figured this out after I saw this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following attribute in your XML in your ListView node, however I might be wrong, but I actually think ListView stacks on top already by default...

```
android:stackFromBottom

Used by ListView and GridView to stack their content from the bottom.

Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".

This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol stackFromBottom.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3astackFromBottom